# How to avoid spammy links affecting us before SERP rankings going down

Tags: seo, google-search-console, seo-audit

We have recently discovered a host of spammy links pointing to our website been put up in last 1 month through webmaster tool
We have not engaged any seo agency/link building and have never created these links

Worst, these are spammy forum sites and almost some-one seems making an attack to our site as the link and keyword is same in all these sites
Till not Have not received any warning, however as it has come to our notice - before any SERP getting down - we want to action this out

One thing we have observed is that - All these spammy links points to a single inner page of website

Pl suggest as have

a) Will Google disvow tool will work by stating to disvow these links

or

b) Is it a good way if we make this specific page 'nofollow' and even 'noindex'
The reasoning behind this is like if the page is not followed and not indexed - the negative links pointing to the page of the site is already no follow and may be out from google serp

or what's the best alternate way to tackle this. Pl suggest in urgent help and advise required

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you such ways to prevent SERP rankings down:

- Use Google Disavow Links Tool to reject the affect of spammy links. The tool may be found here https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/disavow-links-main
  For the step-by-step instruction, follow the links listed by AOV SEO.
- Another way is to contact webmaster of the forum to remove bad links manually, but my experience tells it will not help, because if it is spammy forum it means webmaster does not supervise it and will not hear your requests.

After you have disavowed bad links you may to inform Google about bad site with spam links or/and content using the next form https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreportform

> One thing we have observed is that - All these spammy links points to a single inner page of website

I think it is because this page contains information of niche with high competition and your competitors want to decrease SERP ranking of it.
If you know the resources of competitors which have done it, you may use the form of spamreport to inform Google about their "black" strategies.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Google Webmaster tool disavow tool to remove unatural links is a good way or you can also contact the webmaster or owner of the site directly by creating a formal email to request link removal. Below are the sites to give you more information:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2648487
http://www.bruceclay.com/blog/2012/05/penguin-recovery-link-pruning/